# Mixed signals separation

Tags: matlab, signal-analysis

I have an unknown number of senors that sends the same pluse with different delays, the receiver receives a mixed signals. Is there any method to separate the signals and determine the number of sensors ?

Ps : I'm using MATLAB.

Answer (score 1):

The typical method is to use the cross correlation function to recognize the start of each pulse sequence. Typically pulse patterns are chosen for good autocorrelation properties for this very purpose (likely the start of the packet as a header if there is a random data payload also involved). "Good autocorrelation properties" refer to an autocorrelation that is very strong when the sequence is aligned to itself but very weak for any other delays between the sequence and itself (white noise has this property). If the sequence correlates to delayed versions of itself, it will be difficult to differentiate in time when the sequence was received or to differentiate from separate sensors if they all use the same sequence.